# React native how to listen context change in lifecycle

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

## Overview

Use `React.createContext()` replace `props`, but also want to know what changed in child component.So I use lifecycle `componentWillReceiveProps` or the other who has `nextContext` argument.

And now, when I `setState` value and console `nextContext` or `this.context`,but get nothing `{}`

## Code

Provider

```
//I create a context to transmit data
const {Provider,Consumer} = React.createContext({visible:true});

export default class extends Component {
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            visible:false,
        };
    }

    toggleMenus=()=>{
        let visible = this.state.visible;
        this.setState({visible:!visible})
    };



    render(){
        return (
            <Provider value={{visible:this.state.visible}}>
                <View style={{flex:1}}
                      onStartShouldSetResponder={this.toggleMenus}
                >
                    <Menus />
                </View>
            </Provider>
        )
    }
}
```

Consumer

```
class Menus extends React.Component {
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps, nextContext) {
        console.log(nextProps, nextContext, this.context)//{},{},{}
        //I cant get nextContext to listen context change
    }

    shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState, nextContext) {
        return false //UI still update
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <Consumer>
                {({visible})=>
                    <Text>{visible?1:2}</Text>
                }
            </Consumer>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I solved it.

class need manual assign ContextObject contextType

## Reason

> reference https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#classcontexttype

The `contextType` property on a class can be assigned a Context object created by `React.createContext()`. This lets you consume the nearest current value of that Context type using `this.context`. You can reference this in any of the lifecycle methods including the render function.

## Code

commit

```
- const {Provider,Consumer} = React.createContext({visible:true});
+ const MenusContext = React.createContext({visible:true});

- <Provider value={{visible:this.state.visible}}>
+ <MenusContext.Provider value={{visible:this.state.visible}}>

- <Consumer>
+ <MenusContext.Consumer>
```

Consumer

```
Menus.contextType = MenusContext;
```

## ⚠️Note

`shouldComponentUpdate` cant listen context change only, so when context change ,UI will change as well even if `return false` in `shouldComponentUpdate` life.